# How to compute "y_train_true, y_train_prob, y_test_true, y_test_prob"?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have computed `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test`. But I can not compute `y_train_true, y_train_prob, y_test_true, y_test_prob`.

How can I compute `y_train_true, y_train_prob, y_test_true, y_test_prob` from the following code ?

## X_train:

[image]

## X_test:

[image]

## y_train:

[image]

## y_test:

[image]

**N.B**,

> y_train_true: True binary labels of 0 or 1 in the training dataset
>
> y_train_prob: Probability in range {0,1} predicted by the model for the training dataset
>
> y_test_true: True binary labels of 0 or 1 in the testing dataset
>
> y_test_prob: Probability in range {0,1} predicted by the model for the testing dataset
>
> ---

Code :

```
# Split test and train data
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = np.array(dataset.ix[:, 1:10])
y = np.array(dataset['benign_malignant'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

#Define Classifier and ====
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2)
# knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=11)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = knn.predict(X_train)
```

Comment: what does the data in y_test and y_train look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in your case `y_train` and `y_test` is already `y_train_true` and `y_test_true`. To get `y_train_prob` and `y_test_prob`, you need to take a model. I don't know which dataset you're using but it seems to be a binary classification problem so that you could use logistic regression to do this so,

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_train_prob = knn.predict_proba(X_train)
y_test_prob = knn.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Comment: I am using `K nearest neighbors` classification. Are you mean `x_train_prob = y_train_prob` and `x_test_prob =  y_test_prob `?

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque ah yeh sorry for the typo. Updated the solution.

Comment: But I am getting this error  `y_train_prob = knn.proba(X_train)
AttributeError: 'KNeighborsClassifier' object has no attribute 'proba'`

Comment: Sorry it's `predict_proba`. Try it again!